# SocketIO is not listening to 'on' function

Tags: sockets, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I've tried this for 6+ hours now. I am using Flask-SocketIO and react native to just try to get a test setup working. It seems that some listener is not working. Here is my code:

```
SERVER SIDE PYTHON FILE (running on flask development server) 

@socketio.on('connect')
def connect():
    print('listening to connect')


@socketio.on('emission')
def emission(data):
    print('listen to emission')
    message = data['hello']
    emit('emission', message, broadcast=True)


CLIENT SIDE REACT NATIVE

import io from 'socket.io-client/dist/socket.io'; 
socket = null
export default class trial extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props)

        this.state = {
        returned:'',
        }
     }

componentDidMount() { 
    console.log('test')
}

click() {
    //connect
    socket = io.connect('http://127.0.0.1:5000', {transports: 
    ["websocket"]} );


socket.on('emission', (data) => {
    this.setState({returned:data})
    console.log('emission was emitted by someone and sent', data);
    });
}  

click2() {
    socket.disconnect()
}

click3() {
    console.log('emission')
    socket.emit('emission', {hello: 'emitting message to server'});
}
```

I am trying to listen to connect, and that succeeds and Flask development server prints out 'listening to connect'

I am then trying to listen to 'emission', send it a message, then have it sent back. This part wont work and nothing prints to development server.

I have tried socket.io.on , connect and disconnect work

Answer (score 0):

You have to run Flask-SocketIO with

```
python flask_script.py
```

**not**

```
flask run
```

This is to ensure that gevent is running and able to manage websockets; otherwise, anything you use websockets for will not work.